# Associating a particular input method with a specific app

Tags: keyboard, terminal, input-methods, swiftkey

Is there a way to associate a particular input method with a specific app?  For example, I'd like to always use the Hacker's Keyboard with the Terminal Emulator, while using SwiftKey for most other apps.

If this is a feature that requires rooting the phone and possibly installing a custom ROM, please let me know; I'm considering doing this anyway and the availability of such a feature might be my "killer app".

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there's no stable solution available, but you can try [KeySwap](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1146125) to associate specific keyboard to an app.

As Android doesn't allow an app to change Input Method programatically, your device needs to be rooted for this to work.

Comment: Looks promising, but I didn't see any news since 2011. Found something by that name on github but it's about swapping Pgp keys. Do you know if development has continued since then?

Answer (score 0):

I do it with Tasker. 
Note: needs Secure Settings plugin w/ system+ enabled

> Start Hacking (11)
>       A1: Secure Settings [ Configuration:Input Method/Hacker's Keyboard Package:com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin Name:Secure Settings Timeout (Seconds):0 ]
>
> Stop Hacking (12)
>       A1: Secure Settings [ Configuration:Input Method/SwiftKey Package:com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin Name:Secure Settings Timeout (Seconds):0 ]

Very straightforward - 1 profile linking desired apps with the enter/exit tasks above. Over here someone generalized it to return to whatever the previous input method was: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/tasker/gmkPIQy6l7c

But, like OP, these are the only keyboards I use so "hard coding" SwiftKey was alright with me.